# What is the right way to mock an RxJava Observable

Tags: android, testing, rx-java

I have an API which returns `Observable`'s to be used with RxJava. For testing I want to avoid network operations so plan to mock the responses. However as all responses must me wrapped with `Observable` and the `from()` method expects a `Future` not a concrete type, my mock class is convoluted with anonymous wrapper classes and I think there must be a better way.

Here is what I have:

```
public class MockApi implements MyApi {

    @Override
    public Observable<MyData> getMyData() {
        return Observable.from(new Future<MyData>() {

            @Override public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) { return false; }
            @Override public boolean isCancelled() { return false; }
            @Override public boolean isDone() { return false; }

            @Override
            public MyData get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException,
                    ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
                return get();
            }

            @Override
            public MyData get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
                return new MyData();
            }

        });
    }

    ...

}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `return Observable.just(new MyData())` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
return Observable.just(new MyData());
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html). And for more complicated mock => [list of creating operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#creating).

Comment: you should use Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just()) instead

Comment: I don't think so, the returned value will use only once.

Comment: For example, Retrofit can return Observable and you don't subscribe twice on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(new MyData())`, or use PublishSubject for sending data through it. Notice, you have to use .defer() operator in first case because it will use the same value from first call otherwise

Comment: What is the "it" in the sentence "it will use the same value"?

Comment: It's a mock API so should return the same result from the call every time so I don't think I need the defer?